# How to set Grouping Horizotally in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

now my Grouping

```
A
B
C
```

I wanted output like

```
A   B  C
10 20 30 
40 50 60
```

Suggest Me

Suppose My stored Procedure returns 5 rows.

```
1    xyz     pow 
2    abc     Def
3    jkl     mno
4    ok      csd
5    wde     okok
```

now i want to diplay that data in crystal report like ...

```
1    2    3    4    5
xyz abc  .............
```

means its Dynamic column right ... so how can i set into crystal report.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?  Please include any error messages you have received.

Comment: added briefly .. cheked in question .. thanks for your interest to solve this question

Comment: What should happen in case your procedure returns 1000 of rows?

Comment: it returns maximum 5 rows only

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is Insert, CrossTab.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use PIVOT in SQL.

See: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query